# How to replace spaces with tabs only on a newline?

Tags: php, regex

I have some multi-line strings that are indented with spaces that I would like to convert to tabs.

Take this script for `example.php`

```
<?php

echo <<<EOT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Example with spaces:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

EOT;
$spaces = <<<EOD
For every new line, replace 2 spaces with 1 tab.
  Here 2 spaces should start with 1 tab.
Ignore         all spaces      that don't begin on a new line.
    Now 4 spaces will be 2 tabs.
 This line starts with only 1 space, so it should remain unchanged.
      And 6 spaces will be 3 tabs.
Still   skipping    all spaces that don't begin on a new line.

EOD;
echo $spaces;

$tabs = <<<EOD
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Example replaced with tabs:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
For every new line, replace 2 spaces with 1 tab.
\tHere 2 spaces should start with 1 tab.
Ignore         all spaces      that don't begin on a new line.
\t\tNow 4 spaces will be 2 tabs.
 This line starts with only 1 space, so it should remain unchanged.
\t\t\tAnd 6 spaces will be 3 tabs.
Still   skipping    all spaces that don't begin on a new line.

EOD;
echo $tabs;
```

My first failed attempt:

```
str_replace("  ", "\t", $spaces);
```

This doesn't work because it will replace multi-spaces in the middle of a line with tabs.

My second failed attempt:

```
preg_replace("/\n(?=[\h]*[\h])/", "\n\t", $spaces);
```

This doesn't work because it only replaces the first two spaces with a tab.

I feel like I'm looking for some sort of variable number of replacements function, or a contextually conditional replacement, like if you see `x` spaces at the beginning of a line, then replace with `0.5x` tabs.

If you're trying to test this out, then I would suggest running it in a console to write to a file that you can reload in a text editor to view the tabs.

```
php example.php > temp.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~(?:^|\G)\h{2}~m', "\t", $spaces)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL7qM8/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:^|\G)` - the beginning of a line/string (`^`) or the end of the previous successful match (`\G`)
- `\h{2}` - 2 horizontal whitespaces.

Since the `m` option is used, `^` will match start of lines, not just the start of string position.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `\G` and it's exactly what I needed